# SQL*Loader control file mapping one data field to two columns

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

I am using a shell script with the `sqlldr` command, to load data from a CSV file into a table.

For example the CSV file with this data:

```
dog;cat;bird;fish;
```

and this control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1) LOAD DATA 
 INFILE *
 APPEND
 INTO TABLE animals
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
 (
animal1, animal2, animal3, animal4)
```

loads into table as expected:

```
ANIMAL1    ANIMAL2    ANIMAL3    ANIMAL4   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
dog        cat        bird       fish
```

But now I would like to load the Data into same table like

```
ANIMAL1    ANIMAL2    ANIMAL3    ANIMAL4   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
dog        fish       bird       fish
```

So instead of 'cat' I would like to have 'fish' in both the second and fourth columns.

How can I modify my control file to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to other fields as part of [an SQL expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-83FF6EDC-C7F8-4F29-8994-59153BE31924), so in this case you can just replace the field value from the file with another field, with bind-variable-type syntax:

```
...
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
  animal1,
  animal2 ":animal4",
  animal3,
  animal4
)
```

After loading your sample CSV with your original control file and one modified as above the table contains:

```
select * from animals;

ANIMAL1    ANIMAL2    ANIMAL3    ANIMAL4   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
dog        cat        bird       fish      
dog        fish       bird       fish
```